# Is there a way to copy an entire NLA sequence from one armature to another, without using python scripts?

Tags: animation, armature, nla-editor

I have a character/armature with an NLA tracks sequence, and I want to copy the whole NLA sequence to another character that uses a similar armature.
I can add the same actions to the second character's NLA tracks, but I would have to redo the entire sequence (which is meant to be exactly the same). How can I copy the whole NLA sequence from one armature to another?

Note: The characters are in separate scenes within the same blend file.